# Translate "Quiet your mind"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, sentence-translation, motto, reflexive-pronoun

I want a proper translation for the English sentence:

> "Quiet your mind"

and also

> "Quiet yourself"

I mean this in the sense of calming your mind and yourself. I want this to be translated as a command (reflective command?) please. Thanks!

I've done quite some googling. I don't know whether to use the present imperative or future imperative. Also, some Latin words I've come with for the verb are:

- *mitescere* (to calm down),
- *quietare* (to be quiet, to rest, to be calm),
- *taceo* (to be silent), and
- *conquiescere* (to rest).

The one I think may fit best is *quietare*, but I could see using *taceo*.

I believe "your mind" will translate to Latin in the vocative but am not sure; so, I need help on that too. For "mind", I would rather use *animus* than *mens* due to the fact I don't mean to refer solely to the physical mind.

Answer (score 3):

*Tacere* means "to be quiet", not "to make quiet".
Unless you want to do something like "make it so that your mind is quiet", *tacere* is not an option.
One possibility in this direction is *cura ut mens tua taceat*, "take care that your mind becomes silent".

The verb *tacere* does work for "quiet yourself".
The simple order *tace* means "be quiet".
If you want to combine the two orders to a single maxim "quiet your mind and yourself", you might want to use two different verbs in Latin.

The verb *quietare* (or deponent *quietari*) seems to mean "to make quiet", but I was unable to find any classical attestations.
However, it is a very naturally derived word for this meaning, so I have nothing against using it unless you have a specific era or style you want to follow.
This appears to be a transitive verb, so you can make "your mind" into an accusative object.

The most suitable words for "mind" in this context seem to be *mens*, *animus*, and *anima*.
You can compare these words in [a number of online Latin dictionaries](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/867/79).
If you want it to mean more "mind" than "soul", I recommend *mens*.

This brings me to the translation *mentem tuam quieta*, which is very literally "quiet your mind".
I would tweak this a little and use dative instead of a possessive pronoun (which plays the role of a genitive of *ego* here).
With dative it becomes more "quiet the mind for yourself"; it indicates that you will benefit from quieting your mind.

I like having the two orders together, and certain emphasis can be added by putting the imperatives at the ends.
My recommendation is this phrase (or a part thereof if you only want one at a time):

> *Tace et mentem tibi quieta.*
>   Be silent and quiet your mind.